# I want to install Fedora in Virtual Box with a Usb stick

Tags: 13.04, virtualbox, usb-drive, fedora

I managed to install Virtual Box on my Ubuntu system; now I want to install Fedora within the virtual machine. I have a Fedora image installed on a usb stick that is accessible by a vmdk file - an image used to install Fedora on a system if no OSes were on my computer. I specify that file as an hard drive to my virtual machine, hoping than the system would see it as a partition from where I might install Fedora, but that's not what happens. The system tells me it cannot boot from that drive. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Just add a virtual CD-ROM drive to the virtual machine and assign the Fedora ISO image to it. Don't make it harder by using VMware image files on VirtualBox of which was an ISO in the first place. Use common sense.

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer on http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Fedora-17-in-Virtualbox; i'll follow instructions there.

Comment: In fact, the only thing that happens is that I freeze on the panel supposed to ask me to install Fedora on my system.